# How to delete and add rows based on if cell is in table

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel I have a the following set up in Sheet 1

```
  A   B     C     D     E
1 a   12    123     
2 b   234   2342        
3 c   12    23    54    342
4 d   234   33    54    
5 e   234   34    66    
6 f   345
```

and the table below in Sheet 2

```
  A B
1 b 2
2 d 3
3 e 1
```

Sheet 2 determines if some extra rows should be added to Sheet 1 or not, and if not, the row should be deleted.

Giving the result below in Sheet 1

```
   A    B     C     D
 1 b    234   2342  
 2          
 3          
 4 d    234   33    54
 5
 6
 7          
 8 e    234   34    66
 9
```

Note that b,d & e were the only rows remaining from the original data and also the number of rows added below that row relate to the number in column B in sheet 2 for each remaining row.

I would like to use VBA to carry this out. I have read that deleting rows based on criteria means you need to go through a loop from the bottom row to the top row, but I am struggling to make it work for my example.

Here is the code I have used so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Sub maketab()


Range("A1").Select
Dim r As Long
lr = Range("A1").Row
hr = Range("A1").Offset(8 - 1).Row

For r = hr To lr Step -1

    Dim given_rng As Range

    Set given_rng = Sheet2.Range("A1")
    Dim p As Long
    lr_small = given_rng.Row
    hr_small = given_rng.End(xlDown).Row

    For p = hr_small To lr_small Step -1
            If Range("A" & r).Value = Range("A" & p).Value Then
                'Add a row below
                Range("A" & r).Offset(1).Select
                Selection.Resize(Sheet2.Range("A" & p).Offset(0, 1).Value).EntireRow.Insert
                Range("A" & r).Select
            Else
                'Delete a row
                Rows(r & ":" & r).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
    Next p
Next r

End Sub
```

As always any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi @h.l.m  Your code is missing an `If` statement in the `p = hr_small To lr_small Step -1` loop. Im getting an `End If without Block If` error.

Comment: oups I removed the EndIf it was a condition i wanted to add before, but decided to remove it for the minimum example in the question. The question is now edited to deal with this...

Comment: @h.l.m sheet 2 colA for matching to sheet 1 and sheet 2 colB for adding row to sheet 1 right?

Comment: @ZAT Yup that's right...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim xlws1 As Worksheet
Dim xlws2 As Worksheet
Dim xlws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

'setting sheet variables
Set xlws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set xlws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set xlws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

k = 1 'setting initial value of k
i = 1 'setting initial value of i
Do While IsEmpty(xlws1.Range("A" & i)) = False
    j = 1 'resetting j

    Do While IsEmpty(xlws2.Range("A" & j)) = False 'setting loop up

        If xlws1.Range("A" & i).Value = xlws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then 'if value matches current sheet 1 value

            xlws1.Rows(i).Copy ' copy row
            xlws3.Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste row
            k = k + 1 'increment k
            Exit Do ' move on
        End If

    j = j + 1 'increment j
    Loop

    i = i + 1 'increment i
Loop


End Sub
```